# Send-MailMessage fails on long unc file name with $ character

Tags: powershell

Testing this for another script Im working on, but having trouble with a new group of files.  See below.  $Attach2 causes the error while $Attachment1 works fine

```
$Attachment1 = "c:\temp\I went to the beach-and  now too.txt"
$Attach2 = '\\qa-west\e$\orders\15557__45747457-Re_[EXTERNAL]SomeBoxShipmentTestName-JoeSmithers-FileWest-232264_42211_3674745752.msg'
$smtpServer = "mail.somewhare.com"

try{
    Send-MailMessage -From 'nobody@somwhare.com' -To 'testdev@somewhare.com' -Subject 'test sub' -Body 'this is body' -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Attachments $Attachment1
}
catch {    
    # log the error
    $ErrorMessage = $PSItem.Exception.Message

    #-- test
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage

}
```

> Send-MailMessage fails with exception:
>
> Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the 
>   specified file.\r\n   at 
>   System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecorderrorRecord)
>
> ```
>  ErrorDetails:Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path did not resolve to a file  FileName $null
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the $- I think it's the square brackets. Square brackets are [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6) in PowerShell, and [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6) doesn't support wildcards in -Attachments

Add a backtick (`) in front of the two square brackets in your filename. There's some more details about this issue available [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7999)